# Overriding inner/subclass fields

Tags: c#, .net, class

I currently have a 'Customer' class that looks like:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string email { get; set; }                          
    public string first_name { get; set; }                     
    public string middle_name { get; set; }                    
    public string last_name { get; set; }                      
}
```

However, I also have another class that wraps the 'Customer' as part of a REST 'GET' request:

```
public class CustomerRequest 
{
    Customer customer;
}
```

In my CustomerRequest, I'd like to make the email field required.  In other words, I'd like to override the default behavior of the Customer class to throw an ArgumentNullException if the email isn't entered upon object creation.  I'd only like to enforce this requirement as part of the CustomerRequest, NOT the customer.

I've tried to make the underlying Customer class fields 'virtual', but this still doesn't allow me to override them in the CustomerRequest class.

How can I achieve my desired functionality?

Comment: `new CustomerRequest(string email)` then set the Customer.email property to the email provided in the CustomerRequest .ctor.

Comment: `I've tried to make the underlying Customer class fields 'virtual', but this still doesn't allow me to override them in the CustomerRequest class.` well of course not. `CustomerRequest` doesn't inherit from `Customer` so it can't override it. If you want to override it then you need to subclass `Customer`.

Comment: Are you using MVC/WebApi?

Answer (score 1):

For whatever it's worth, I'd rethink throwing exceptions in a constructor. Doing so causes the exception to be caught and rethrown as an ObjectInitializationException by the runtime--an operation completely outside your control. These exceptions can be obscure and difficult to pin down, especially to developers who aren't familiar with the object model.

What you might do instead is put a Validate method on the CustomerRequest object that verifies that all required fields are populated (in this case, the email address). Sure, it requires a manual method invocation, but it's explicit, and it doesn't unexpectedly surprise you at runtime.

Comment: This seems like it's a comment on somebody else's answer rather than an answer to the OP.

Comment: Yes and no. He wants to throw an exception when the object is constructed. I'm proposing an alternative solution that may serve him more effectively from a maintenance perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't change the behaviour of `Customer` just because it's a field in another class.

Longer answer: there are a couple of ways of achieving what you're looking for. @MetroSmurf's answer is probably the simplest, but you could also change the `customer` field on `CustomerRequest` to be a property and perform the check there i.e.

```
public class CustomerRequest 
{
    private Customer _customer;
    public Customer Customer
    {
        get { return _customer; }
        set 
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.email))
            {  
                throw new ArgumentNullException("email");
            }
            _cutomer = value;
        }
    }
}
```

But honestly, you'd just be better off validating the CustomerRequest when you recieve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public CustomerRequest
{
    public Customer customer {get;set;}

    public CustomerRequest(Customer c) 
    {
        this.customer = CheckEmail(c);
    }

    private Customer CheckEmail(Customer c) 
    {
        if (c.email == null) throw ArgumentNullException;
        return c;
    }
}
```